# Ruby on Rails 4.0 Tutorial chapter 3 Hell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, installation

`` `I have been trying to solve this problem for almost 3 hours now without success.
 WHen I try to run ``$ rails generate rspec:install` from the tutorial in chapter 3, I get this output:

```
/home/patrick/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:30:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `require'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Application.rb

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end

config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework  :rspec
end

patrick@X67895:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activemodel (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.9)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
capistrano (2.15.4)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
highline (1.6.19)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
jbuilder (1.4.2, 1.0.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.1, 2.2.1)
json (1.8.0)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.7.4)
multi_json (1.7.7)
net-scp (1.1.1)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
pg (0.15.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
railties (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.0.rc2, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.2.0, 1.1.1)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

I have absolutely no idea what do do next. If anybody here knows his rails, please post the answer, or if you are willing to teamview, please respond.
THanks!

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot help much if we don't have any code

Comment: Please show us `config/application.rb`.

Comment: Added the application.rb

Comment: Did you ask this twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Tutorial stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159097/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-stuck)

Answer (score 1):

The config block needs to be inside SampleApp::Application