# Ruby on Rails Tutorial stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to solve this problem for almost 3 hours now without success. When I try to run `rails generate rspec:install` from the tutorial in chapter 3, I get this output:

```
/home/patrick/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:30:in `': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `require'
    from /home/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:46:in `'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'
```

Application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end

config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework  :rspec
end

patrick@X67895:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activemodel (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.9)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
capistrano (2.15.4)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
highline (1.6.19)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
jbuilder (1.4.2, 1.0.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.1, 2.2.1)
json (1.8.0)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (4.7.4)
multi_json (1.7.7)
net-scp (1.1.1)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (2.6.7)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
pg (0.15.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
railties (4.0.0.rc2, 4.0.0.rc1, 3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
rspec-rails (2.13.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.9)
sass-rails (4.0.0.rc2, 3.2.6)
sdoc (0.3.20)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.0)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.14)
turbolinks (1.2.0, 1.1.1)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.1.1)
```

I have absolutely no idea what do do next.

Comment: Post some code and explain what you can't do, what error messages you get, etc, and please edit your title to an explicit one, and related to your problem. It's not the purpose of this site to find someone for helping you on teamviewer

Comment: Which tutorial are you talking about? Could you add a link?

Answer (score 3):

Move your config inside the class, like so:

```
module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework  :rspec
    end

  end
end
```